# Cannot call 'math.round' with argument 'precision'='close'. An argument of 'series float' type was used but a 'simple int' is expected; PINE SCRIPT

Tags: pine-script

im practising pine script, and im doing a simple strategy. but i got this error, can anyone help me? thanks !

```
//@version=5
strategy("Mi semaforo", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

mm_g = ta.sma(close, 5)
mm_y= ta.sma(close, 10)
mm_r = ta.sma(close, 20)

alcista = (mm_g > mm_y) and (mm_y > mm_r)
// bajista = (mm_g < mm_y) and (mm_y < mm_r)

comprado = strategy.position_size > 0

if (not comprado and alcista) 
    cantidad = math.round(strategy.equity, close)
    strategy.entry("Compra", strategy.long, cantidad)

if (comprado and not alcista) 
    strategy.close("Compra", comment="Venta")
```

LINE OF ERROR = cantidad = math.round(strategy.equity, close)

ERROR = line 17: Cannot call 'math.round' with argument 'precision'='close'. An argument of 'series float' type was used but a 'simple int' is expected;
line 17: Variable 'cantidad' is not found in scope '#global_#0', cannot register side effect

Answer (score 0):

The `precision` argument is to round the decimal places.

> If the `precision` parameter is used, returns a float value rounded to
> that amount of decimal places.

For example `math.round(3.1234, 2)` would return `3.12`.

When in doubt, please refer to the reference manual.

Comment: I have a bad parameter, thank you for your help sr !!!!

Comment: You cannot use `close` as precision argument as the error message tells you. It does not make any sense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: it was = cantidad = math.round(strategy.equity / close)   , im sorry :) im learning